# MNIST not outputting correct prediction - school project

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, tensorflow, keras

I created a simple python script that will open a small window and allow user to draw a digit 1-9. When I test it, it continuously outputs the wrong number but says it is 98% accurate when training. Sometimes it would get stuck and just outputting the same digit no matter what was drawn so I thought to delete the old model and  temp file but that did not work. Here is the code for the model training and the GUI

Apologies for my ugly code, I am new to python

model.py

```
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.src.saving.saving_api import load_model
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Flatten, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import mnist
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import os



#delete old stuff
if os.path.exists("temp_canvas.ps"):
    # Delete the file
    os.remove("temp_canvas.ps")
if os.path.exists("mnist_model.keras"):
    # Delete the file
    os.remove("mnist_model.keras")
# Load and preprocess the MNIST dataset
(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = mnist.load_data()
train_images = train_images.reshape((60000, 28, 28, 1))
train_images = train_images.astype('float32') / 255

test_images = test_images.reshape((10000, 28, 28, 1))
test_images = test_images.astype('float32') / 255

train_labels = to_categorical(train_labels)
test_labels = to_categorical(test_labels)

# Create the model
model = Sequential([
    Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(28, 28, 1)),
    MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
    Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
    MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
    Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
    Flatten(),
    Dense(64, activation='relu'),
    Dense(10, activation='softmax')
])

# Compile the model
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

# Train the model
model.fit(train_images, train_labels, epochs=5, batch_size=64, validation_data=(test_images, test_labels))

# Save the model
model.save('mnist_model.h5')



def preprocess_image(image):
    # Convert the canvas image to the correct format
    image = Image.fromarray(image)
    image = image.resize((28, 28)).convert('L')  # Resize and convert to grayscale
    image_for_display = np.array(image)  # 2D array for display
    image_for_model = image_for_display.reshape(1, 28, 28, 1)  # 4D array for model
    image_for_model = image_for_model / 255.0  # Normalize
    return image_for_display, image_for_model



def predict_digit(image):
    mnist_model = load_model('mnist_model.h5')
    image = image.reshape(1, 28, 28, 1)  # 4D array for model
    image = image / 255.0  # Normalize
    prediction = mnist_model.predict(image)
    return np.argmax(prediction, axis=1)[0]  # Return the predicted digit
```

digit-decoder.py

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox
from model import predict_digit
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import time
import os




class DigitDecoder:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.title("Draw a Letter")
        #set up window
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self.root, width=400, height=400)
        self.canvas.pack()
        #add identify button
        self.identify_button = tk.Button(self.root, text="What am I?", command=self.identify_letter)
        self.identify_button.pack()
        #add reset button
        self.reset_button = tk.Button(self.root, text="Reset", command=self.reset_canvas)
        self.reset_button.pack()

        self.old_x = None
        self.old_y = None


        self.setup()
        self.root.mainloop()

    def setup(self):
        self.canvas.bind('<B1-Motion>', self.paint)
        self.canvas.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', self.reset)

    def show_popup(self, message):
        messagebox.showinfo("Information", message)

    #draw the digit
    def paint(self, event):
        if self.old_x and self.old_y:
            self.canvas.create_line(self.old_x, self.old_y, event.x, event.y,
                                    width=12, capstyle=tk.ROUND, smooth=tk.TRUE)

        self.old_x = event.x
        self.old_y = event.y



    #DEBUGGING
    def display_preprocessed_image(self, image):
        # Ensure the image is 2D for grayscale
        if len(image.shape) > 2:
            image = image.squeeze()  # Reducing to 2D if necessary

        # Create a new window
        image_window = tk.Toplevel(self.root)
        image_window.title("Preprocessed Image")

        # create paint window
        image_canvas = tk.Canvas(image_window, width=image.shape[1], height=image.shape[0])
        image_canvas.pack()

        # draw  digit
        for i in range(image.shape[0]):
            for j in range(image.shape[1]):
                pixel_intensity = image[i, j]
                color = f'#{pixel_intensity:02x}{pixel_intensity:02x}{pixel_intensity:02x}'
                image_canvas.create_rectangle(j, i, j+1, i+1, outline=color, fill=color)

    #DEBUGGING
    def preprocess_for_display(self, image):
        image = Image.fromarray(image)
        image = image.resize((28, 28)).convert('L')  # decrease size n convert to grayscale
        return np.array(image)  # 2D array for display

    def preprocess_for_model(self, image):
        image = Image.fromarray(image)
        image = image.resize((28, 28)).convert('L')  # decrease size n  convert to grayscale
        image = np.array(image)
        image = image.reshape(1, 28, 28, 1)  # Reshape for the model
        image = image / 255.0
        return image
    def reset(self, event):
        self.old_x = None
        self.old_y = None

    #takes in the drawn image and runs it through the mnist model and outputs what the model think the letter is.
    def identify_letter(self):
        # Get the canvas drawing as a image
        self.canvas.postscript(file='temp_canvas.ps', colormode='color')
        canvas_image = Image.open('temp_canvas.ps')
        canvas_image = canvas_image.convert('RGB')

        # convert image to a numpy array
        canvas_array = np.array(canvas_image)

        image_for_display = self.preprocess_for_display(canvas_array)

        # display the preprocessed image for debugging
        #DEBUGGING USE ONLY
        self.display_preprocessed_image(image_for_display)

        # prreprocess the image for the model
        image_for_model = self.preprocess_for_model(canvas_array)

        # Call the prediction function from model.py
        digit = predict_digit(image_for_model)

        # Print and show the prediction result
        print(f"Predicted Digit: {digit}")
        self.show_popup(f"The predicted digit is: {digit}")
        if os.path.exists('temp_canvas.ps'):
            os.remove('temp_canvas.ps')

        time.sleep(1)
        self.root.destroy()

    #reset the drawing area
    def reset_canvas(self):
        self.canvas.delete("all")


# Create an instance of the application
app = DigitDecoder()
```

Comment: The MNIST dataset is not meant to create a general digit recognition model, its an academic dataset, what you are trying will never work with a model trained on MNIST.

Comment: What was your training metrics? Accuracy etc.  Could you also post a sample image of your user input? drawing on 28x28 pixel is very hard; maybe downscaling?  Start with simpler conditions. Can you do 1 vs 0 ?  Try generating your own dataset to train; maybe 10x each digit + image augmentation -> 200 images per class. This would give you much better understanding on where your model needs to be changed to work rather than on MNIST.

Comment: Do you draw white numbers on black background, or vice-versa? The MNIST dataset is black-on-white, and when your numbers are white-on-black, the models performance drops significantly.